# How to do String.Join while deserializing a JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My JSON string

```
{
    "account_id": "123456",
    "capabilities": [
        2,
        6,
        15,
        11
    ],
   "currency": "USD"
}
```

My class definition

```
public class AdAccount
{
    public long account_id { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public List<int> capabilities { get; set; }
}
```

Desearialization code:

```
var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(data, new JsonSerializerSettings() { MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Ignore });
```

This all works fine. However what I want is that "capabilities" should be a comma separated string like "2,6,15,11". So I tried

```
public class AdAccount
{
    public long account_id { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    private string _capabilities;
    public string capabilities { get { return _capabilities; } set { _capabilities = String.Join(",", value); } }
}
```

But this throws an exception

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path
>   'capabilities', line 1, position 544.

Is it possible to do what I want during deserialization?

Thanks.

Comment: @rjv_mjn did you tried `public String capabilities { get; set; }`instead of `public List<int> capabilities { get; set; }`

Comment: Why would you want your in-memory representation to be harder to work with? Surely it would be better to transform the list in your *nicer* representation (`Account`) only when you need to.

Comment: @JonSkeet My objective in the code I am writing is to get the JSON string and put it in dB where we do a bit of processing with data. The "capabilities" value is not of much importance to us but we would not like the code to throw away any data that we receive. JSON -> Deserialized Obj -> DB. Thanks.

Comment: @VeeKayBee, tried that. It throws the same exception. Thanks.

Comment: @rjv_rnjn: It sounds like your DB-type is specialized for the DB - so I would deserialize to an entity which has the type in its more *natural* state, then convert to a DB-specific representation. It's easy to go from one representation to another, after all.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think I'll go that route; seems like a cleaner approach. Thanks.

Comment: I've added that approach as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have two representations:

- The "natural" representation which has the `List<int>`
- The "database" representation which has the joined `string`

You can easily write converters from one to the other, and it means you don't need to do anything special in the serialization/deserialization paths themselves. The cost is that you end up with two models, of course. I'd recommend making the vast majority of your code use the "natural" representation - only use the DB representation as a stepping stone for when you're dealing with the database.

Comment: I chose this answer as this made me not write custom code for one specific instance and also made more sense (although as mentioned a little bit of redundancy). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you make an additional property to hold the display value (your CSV). This property would be read-only, and would update/recalculate itself when your list updates.

```
public class AdAccount
{
    public long account_id { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public List<int> capabilities { get; set; }

    public string capabilitiesDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(", ", capabilities);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if you need to add an ignore for the Json parser to ignore the property.

The benefit of this approach is that the value is only calculated when you go to access the value.

Comment: `The benefit of this approach is that the value is only calculated when you go to access the value.` and everytime you access the value.

Comment: @I4V, yes, it would be calculated on _every_ access. For something trivial, this would be ok. But I can understand for larger systems you might want to look at a lazy loading implementation.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks. If all fails I may end up doing a read only property. Since it is accessed only once, the performance shouldn't be that bad. Also, the int array is 5-10 items at the most.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom *Converter* which can do the implicit conversion from `List<int>` to string

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdAccount>(json,new MyConverter());
```

.

```
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(string) && reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            List<long> nums = new List<long>();
            reader.Read();
            while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
            {
                nums.Add((long)reader.Value);
                reader.Read();
            }
            return String.Join(",", nums);
        }
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class AdAccount
{
    public long account_id { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string capabilities { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: He want's it the other way around though (a List<int> to be parsed as a comma-separated string).

Comment: What I mean is the json coming in is a list. Your deserializer take a string instead. :)

Comment: @SimonBelanger And I think this is what OP wants :))

Comment: @I4V thanks for the code but my JSON will not be what your code expects (as I understand). It is an incoming array of integers which I was trying to convert to a string; and not a string.

Comment: @rjv_rnjn I thought the class you want to use in your code is `Account`. so your final class is `AdAccount` and json is always an integer array?

Comment: @I4V, sorry for that mix up. I've corrected the class name. I was showing two different things that I tried (same class with different property type). The JSON element "capabilities" is always an integer array. Thanks.

Comment: @I4V, thanks for the answer & code but I think I'll skip on writing custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

Have an additional property which is parsed version of your `List<int>` Property and set it inside setter of `List<int>` property.

```
public class AdAccount
{
    public long account_id { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    private List<int> _capabilities;
    public List<int> capabilities
    {
        get { return _capabilities; }
        set { _capabilities = value; this.ParsedCapabilities = string.Join(",", value); }
    }
    public string ParsedCapabilities { get; set; }
}
```